# Call protocol default implementation in inherence tree

Tags: swift, protocols

This is a very similar question: [Calling protocol default implementation from regular method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602712/calling-protocol-default-implementation-from-regular-method), BUT none of the answers cover the case when **inherance plays a role**. The answer suggest casting it to the protocol type itself will solve it, but not in this case (Copy paste in playground):

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    func sayCheese()
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    func sayHi() {
        print("Hi, I am protocol")
        sayCheese()
    }

    func sayCheese() {
        print("Cheese from protocol")
    }
}

public class MyFirstClass: MyProtocol {
    public func sayCheese() {
        print("Cheese from 1")

        (self as MyProtocol).sayCheese()
    }
}

public class MySecondClass: MyFirstClass {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        sayHi()
    }

    public func sayHi() {
        print("Hi from 2")
        super.sayHi()
    }

    public override func sayCheese() {
        print("Said cheese from 2")
        super.sayCheese()
    }
}

MySecondClass()
```

It prints the following:

```
...
Said cheese from 2
Cheese from 1
Said cheese from 2
Cheese from 1
...
```

In instance of `MyFirstClass`, how can I call the default implementation of MyProtocol of method `sayCheese`?

Edit: My usecase is the following:
I have a protocol which is adopted by a class, which is subclassed a lot. The protocol has multiple default methods, which can call eachother. Some of the subclasses needs to override the methods, do stuff, and call `super.method()` (to finally call the default implementation of the protocol, because a superclass may have overriden the protocol default implementation as well). So I really need dynamic dispatching.

Comment: You need to remove the `sayCheese()` requirement from the protocol to get the static dispatch that the answer to the question you linked relies on.

Comment: @dan See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although protocols support concrete implementations using extension but that defies the concept of a `protocol`

> A protocol defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other
>   requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality.

and it should be avoided as much as possible until you are truly sure this will not be `overriden`.

**Solution 1:**

If you have been into a situation mentioned then i would suggest to introduce an intermediary `class` that does nothing except conforming to that `protocol` and then inherit `subClasses` from that `class`.

```
public class Intermediary: MyProtocol {}

public class MyFirstClass: Intermediary {
    public func sayCheese() {
        print("Cheese from 1")

        super.sayCheese()
    }
}

public class MySecondClass: MyFirstClass {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        sayHi()
    }

    public func sayHi() {
        print("Hi from 2")
        super.sayHi()
    }

    public override func sayCheese() {
        print("Said cheese from 2")
        super.sayCheese()
    }
}
```

Now creating object `MySecondClass()` will print the below output,

```
Hi from 2
Hi, I am protocol
Cheese from protocol
```

---

**Solution 2:**

As mentioned in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602712/calling-protocol-default-implementation-from-regular-method), remove `sayCheese` method from the `protocol` so your protocol declaration will be empty but `sayCheese` will stay in the `extension` and it will break the recursive calls to `sayCheese` allowing your app to not freeze.

```
public protocol MyProtocol {}
```